# Dynamically modifying a block at runtime

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, objective-c-runtime

I'm trying to make a good block-based initializer for an objective-c class. I'm declaring it in a superclass and I want it to be useful in all subclasses.

Right now I have:

```
+ (id)createWithBlock:(void (^) (id newObject))creationBlock {
    id newObject = [self object];    
    creationBlock(newObject);
    return newObject;
}
```

Which can be used (in a subclass) as such:

```
Record *newRecord = [Record createWithBlock:^(id newObject) {
    Record *newRecord = (Record *)newObject;
    newRecord.name = @"Ginger";
    newRecord.type = @"Rhizome";
}];
```

This is okay for now, but I'd love to get this pared down a bit. Ideally it would look like:

```
Record *newRecord = [Record createWithBlock:^{
    name = @"Ginger";
    type = @"Rhizome";
}];
```

But that seems a bit ambitious. I would also be okay with just:

```
Record *newRecord = [Record createWithBlock:^(Record *newRecord) {
    newRecord.name = @"Ginger";
    newRecord.type = @"Rhizome";
}];
```

This last version is difficult because it seems clang does some compile-time type checking for blocks. The above won't compile with the definition of createWithBlock: that I have above, because: `incompatible block pointer types initializing 'void (^)(struct Record *)', expected 'void (^)(struct objc_object *)`.

If it didn't do this strong type checking I could just swizzle the methods at runtime. (Or maybe I could do that right now if I typedef my block declaration?)

I've been scratching my head on this for a while, and I've read pretty much every document on blocks I could find, including the clang spec. If anyone has ideas I'd love to hear them, this is for an open source project and I think the pattern would benefit all objective-c users.

Right now my thoughts are leaning towards `imp_implementationWithBlock()`. But then I'd need to "construct" a new IMP based on what's in that one, and swap it out. Feasible?

Comment: Exactly what does this achieve over just initialising the properties *after* the constructor? (Regardless, I'd just swallow the verbose syntax; until Apple sees fit to add generics to ObjC, it's an idiom that won't surprise people using your API.)

Comment: It's more a style/readability thing than a functionality thing. By initializing everything in a block, there's a visual representation of the object that's in one place on the screen. And for more complex initializations, that seems useful to me. (Lots of other languages have this type of creation). EDIT: A few other languages.

Comment: Maybe instead of defining a single initialiser in a superclass, you could have a preprocessor macro generate the typesafe definition for the third syntax variant for you. A bit boilerplatish but seems like a reasonable nonmagical compromise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What compiler are you using? I believe recent versions of LLVM will accept the last code example you give. (i.e. The error you give shouldn't happen.)

In particular, this works for me with LLVM 3.1 in a brand-new Xcode project in Xcode 4.3.3.

Comment: This is very helpful! Stupidly, my `createWithBlock` was being compiled with LLVM 3.1, and my use of that method was compiled with LLVM GCC 4.2. Switched to the new compiler and it does work! Any ideas for my "ideal"?

Comment: If you really want to reduce character count, all I can think of is using a macro or using something like passing a var_args list of key-value pairs to set.

Comment: Well, I've already got a create method that takes an NSDictionary. I was hoping there would be some way to sort of "inspect" a block and create a new block based on it?

Comment: I don't know of any way to get your original block to compile without macros or similar tricks, since name and type are not in scope. Even if you could compile it, I don't think there is any supported API to modify a block to point at a different object. (And the dictionary method will be fairly clean with Objective-C dict literals.)

Comment: It's pretty slick: `[Record create:@{@"name" : @"Squash", @"type": @"Vegetable"}];` (Record is a vanilla NSManagedObject). Thanks for the help, I guess this is as good as it will get for now. If interested, the category is [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/819)